# Retrieving batch FB reactions from multiple posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, facebook-javascript-sdk

I managed to return the first page of my posts with some details including its ID with:

```
api = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me'
key = 'secret'

payload = {'fields':'''
            posts{permalink_url,created_time,admin_creator,message}'''
           , 'access_token':key}

r = requests.get(api, params = payload)
```

In the FB Graph API documentation, you can do an API call like this `/{object-id}/reactions`, so now with the ID, getting the reactions is possible. But I need to get the reaction counts by type, so after some research, I find out that I will be able to chain the calls like below.

```
reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(1).as(LIKE),
reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(1).as(LOVE),
reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(1).as(WOW),
reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(1).as(HAHA),
reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).summary(1).as(SAD),
reactions.type(ANGRY).limit(0).summary(1).as(ANGRY),
reactions.type(THANKFUL).limit(0).summary(1).as(THANKFUL)
```

Fine now everything is working, but after a pause, I realized that no way in FB will allow me to run those calls for each post especially after I get all the posts IDs since the beginning and sure enough it does not.

So there's this thing about batching as well where I tried to do, where I stacked multiple IDs;

```
fields=id,reactions.type(PRIDE).limit(0).summary(1),reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(1)&ids=id1,id2
```

but I get this instead;

```
"message": "Syntax error \"Field reactions specified more than once. This is only possible before version 2.1\"
```

From here it is quite clear to me that FB does not allow specifying a field more than once but just doing `reactions.limit(0).summary(1)` just returns the total reactions, how am I able to retrieve the reactions from each post without having to bust the API. It gets more confusing as the APIs constantly change throughout time and now we have `v3.2` and most of the methods I have researched on SO does not apply anymore.

Comment: Where did the `.as(…)` go?

Comment: It seems the later APIs do not support aliases for certain endpoints so I removed them.

Comment: Works fine when I test it against v3.2

Comment: Even for batching?

Comment: If by that you mean the `ids=id1,id2` syntax (which isn’t really making batch requests), then Yes.